# Is there any online service for compiling a large number of ConTeXt files?

Tags: compiling, context

I have about 16,000 ConTeXt files that I need to compile.

On my computer, a single file from that list takes 45 minutes to compile, as there are many pages and a lot of calculations done in Lua. This will take 500 days to finish on my computer.

Is there any service that I can use where I just upload all of the TeX files and related subfolders and let some supercomputer compile this fast?

Comment: You could try and put context in a docker container (someone already did: https://github.com/Grummfy/ConTeXt-docker) and run it on AWS

Comment: I second DG's suggestion. If you need different (up-to-date) versions, have a look at https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/images/context.

Comment: @TeXnician You can also use my Docker image, which is the latest beta, updated daily: https://hub.docker.com/r/contextgarden/beta

Comment: @HenriMenke Well, the Island of TeX provides Current, Beta and LMTX (although not updated daily, only weekly). It's probably a good thing to have a choice :)